# How to clone a git project from the website to your desktop?

Tags: windows, git, github

When I try to clone a git repository to my Desktop it always takes me to the [download](http://windows.github.com/) page but it is already downloaded.

How can I clone it directly from the browser to PC ?

Comment: You may want to be more specific, how do you try to clone a git repository (command line, github app for windows?), from where (github, some other support)?

Comment: Easiest to just use the cmd line. Maybe get a virtual term for your browser I spose.
If you'd rather not and your on windows get the windows client which will handle those links for you and clone to directory of your choosing.

Comment: In command line: `git clone <SSH>`. [Getting a Git Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be logged into the website (GitHub.com) and the application and refresh the page.  Then you can click clone to desktop.

You could also install command-line tools.  From the app, Preferences > Advanced > Install Command Line Tools

Comment: Clone in Desktop doesn't seem to work with the latest desktop version. The app is activated, then nothing. This must be the most terrible ui ever, where the obvious action doesn't do anything and the correct action is totally invisible.

Comment: This answer may have been correct when answered, but it isn't correct anymore.  "Clone to desktop" is no longer a labeled button on the website nor is that route still available for installing command line tools (see Anton Dozortsev's comment on the question for the command).  Timmles has a better answer.

Answer (score 17):

The GitHub functionality to 'Clone in Desktop' has been replaced by a drag and drop feature which is not quite clear. The process to do this is explained here: http://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2014/04/github-clone-to-desktop-with-windows.html

Comment: This did fix my problem, where the accepted answer did not.

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me as well. Dragging the URL from the GitHub project page over GitHub for Windows immediately displayed a Clone Repository screen and asked for a directory to clone in.

Comment: So we're saying that a web site dedicated to programmers has a dead button on it that doesn't do what everyone assumes it does ... I mean, is this supposed to be ironic?

Answer (score 1):

They've changed the button now to this tiny one to the right of the url:

[image]

Clicking on it opens the desktop app if you've installed it

Answer (score 0):

I would try using MySysGit, as it seems to work about as well as any Windows git cloner could. You can get it [HERE](http://msysgit.github.io/).